# Newsletter Signup on CMS page in Magento

Tags: magento

How can I add Magento's default newsletter signup module within a CMS page?  Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

found it.

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

Comment: @silvo - it says "you can accept your own answer in 20 hours"

Comment: I didn't know that, well, every day you learn something new :)

Comment: where i should add newsletter translated words for different languages? for example for "Sign up" or for Subscribe our newsletter. I tried adding in locale related folder's Mage_Newsletter.csv file but it did not work. Any help?

Comment: Good stuff,but if insert block via Widgets - need add changes to subscribe.phtml. Change $this->getFormActionUrl() to Mage::getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/new', array('_secure' => true))

Comment: The block type is incorrect, which is what caused the action url to be empty. Type should be "newsletter/subscribe", not "core/template".

Answer (score 28):

The mentioned code adds a signup form to a CMS page, but it was non-working for me.

Changing the block type to `newsletter/subscribe` fixed that. So working code for me was:

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

Comment: I am just amazed that it doesnt for me - running CE 1.7 ...... something in XML or config that might be blocking?

Comment: Make sure to whitelist the `newsletter/subscribe` block :)

Answer (score 11):

Real answer has been added already,

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

but it does not work for some people (on newer versions of Magento). The reason for this, most likely, are block permissions.
The block (`newsletter/subscribe`) is not allowed on frontend by default. Go to

```
System > Permissions > Blocks
```

and enable it.

Answer (score 5):

Use this in the layout update section of the specific page you want to change.

```
<reference name="right">
    <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

[My configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg1tS.png)

Check out the image attached above, it worked for me.
I went to home page's design tab, and added those lines in "Page Layout".

```
<block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="home.footer.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe-mini.phtml" />
```

as you can see those lines in the image too.