# Magento CE 1.9 - How can I add the register newsletter signup checkbox to the edit page?

Tags: php, html, magento

I currently have the newsletter checkbox enabled in:

`/app/design/frontend/new/default/template/customer/form/register.php`

It seems to use the following code in the template file:

```
<?php if ($this->isNewsletterEnabled()): ?>

    <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed"<?php if($this->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="checkbox" />
    <label for="is_subscribed"><?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?></label>

    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter')?>

<?php endif ?>
```

**The Question**

How can I add this same form input to the edit account page?

`/app/design/frontend/new/default/template/customer/form/edit.php`

Copying just the code above gives the following error, which obviously means the needed functions are not being included.

I'm guessing this means I'm missing some XML somewhere ... but where?

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getIsSubscribed() on a non-object`

I think I may need to add the following to a layout file, should this be the `customer.xml` and if so whereabouts in this file? inside this tag `<customer_account_edit translate="label">`?

`{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}`

---

**Research**

I have found the following Magento StackOverflow question but it doesn't answer where the XML goes?

[Newsletter Signup on CMS page in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420285/newsletter-signup-on-cms-page-in-magento)

Comment: You can use the same code, but it seems that the EDIT block doesnt have all the required function, you could rewrite. Where ever that block is called you can makesure that the block type is "customer/register" that may solve it. Else the EDIT block class can extend Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Register class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in /app/design/frontend/new/default/template/customer/form/edit.phtml  file

```
<li class="control">
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" 
               title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" 
               value="1" id="is_subscribed" class="checkbox" />
    </div>
    <label for="is_subscribed">
        <?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>
    </label>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter')?>
</li>
```